# PostgreSQL and temp table triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sequence

I am looking for the best practice to define triggers and sequences on temporary tables with PostgreSQL.

When creating a temp table, PostgreSQL automatically creates a temporary schema with the name "pg_temp_*nnn*" (alias: "pg_temp")

It appears that one can create user functions and objects in this temporary schema.

I wonder if this is really valid SQL for PostgreSQL or just working by accident?

Tested with various PostgreSQL versions from 10 to 14.

Note: Triggers created on temp tables automatically land in the temp schema because the trigger inherits the schema of its table.

Tx!

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt1 (pk INTEGER NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50));
 
CREATE SEQUENCE pg_temp.tt1_seq START 1;

CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.tt1_srl() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
'DECLARE ls BIGINT;
  BEGIN
     SELECT INTO ls nextval(''pg_temp.tt1_seq'');
     IF new.pk ISNULL OR new.pk=0 THEN
        new.pk:=ls;
     ELSE
        IF new.pk>=ls THEN
           PERFORM setval(''pg_temp.tt1_seq'',new.pk);
        END IF;
     END IF;
     RETURN new;
  END;'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER tt1_srlt BEFORE INSERT ON tt1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE pg_temp.tt1_srl();

INSERT INTO tt1 (name) VALUES ('aaaa');
SELECT 'Insert #1:', currval('pg_temp.tt1_seq');

INSERT INTO tt1 VALUES (0,'bbbb');
SELECT 'Insert #2:', currval('pg_temp.tt1_seq');

INSERT INTO tt1 VALUES (100,'cccc');
SELECT 'Insert #3:', currval('pg_temp.tt1_seq');

INSERT INTO tt1 (name) VALUES ('dddd');
SELECT 'Insert #4:', currval('pg_temp.tt1_seq');

SELECT * FROM tt1 ORDER BY pk;



Output:


CREATE TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TRIGGER
INSERT 0 1
  ?column?  | currval
------------+---------
 Insert #1: |       1
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
  ?column?  | currval
------------+---------
 Insert #2: |       2
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
  ?column?  | currval
------------+---------
 Insert #3: |     100
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
  ?column?  | currval
------------+---------
 Insert #4: |     101
(1 row)

 pk  | name
-----+------
   1 | aaaa
   2 | bbbb
 100 | cccc
 101 | dddd
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that works and is supported.

Creating objects in schema `pg_temp` creates temporary objects that will be removed when the session ends. `CREATE TEMP TABLE x (...)` is the same as `CREATE TABLE pg_temp.x (...)`.